# Push_back method works differently in this code. Why?

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define MAX 20
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//Creating a vector
vector <int> v;
std::vector<int>::iterator vIterator;
int i;

for(i=1;i<MAX;i++)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}

cout<<"Numbers:"<<endl;
for(vIterator = v.end();vIterator>v.begin();vIterator--)
{

    cout<<*vIterator<<endl;
}

int el_count = v.size();
cout<<"Size="<<el_count;

return 0;
}
```

Here's the output of the code:

Numbers:
0
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
Size=19

Why am I getting this "0" at the start?
And why does my list begin with a 2?

Comment: End() is past the last element

Comment: Note that `vIterator = v.end()` points at one beyond the actually valid data in the vector. So dereferencing in the 1st cycle is undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `rbegin` and `rend` instead to iterate a container backwards without this hassle.

Comment: Don't ever include anything under `bits`, it's libstdc++ implementation-specific stuff, non portable and subject to change.

Comment: @MatteoItalia There's even a canonical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Change your postfix ++ to prefix, ++ i.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard c++. Who is teaching people to do this?

Comment: It is recommended to use `!=` rather than `<` or `>` to compare iterators while iterating containers. This is to maintain uniformity among all containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the range of indices of a vector is from `v.begin()` to `v.end()-1`. You are instead using it from `v.begin()+1` to `v.end()`.

The statement in the loop should be,

```
for(vIterator = v.end()-1; vIterator>=v.begin(); --vIterator)
```

Accessing `v.end()` would be undefined behaviour, here giving a 0, and clearly you are skipping the first element.

Edit: (Thanks to @Revolver_Ocelot)

As can be seen from the comments, in the last iteration, when `vIterator=v.begin()`, and then `vIterator--` is called, the location pointed by the iterator will result in undefined behaviour. This is because `vIterator>=v.begin()` may or may not be true when `vIterator` is decremented below `v.begin()`. An alternative could be,

```
for(vIterator = v.end()-1; vIterator>v.begin(); --vIterator)
{
    cout<<*vIterator<<endl;
}
cout<<*vIterator<<endl;
```

Another way would be using reverse iterators,

```
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator vIterator;
for(vIterator = v.rbegin(); vIterator!=v.rend(); ++vIterator)
```

Comment: Decrementing iterator equal to `begin()` is UB. Reverse iterators use special care to avoid this. You have to use `break` in the loop, use reverse iterators or handle `.begin()` out of the loop.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Can you please explain how it invokes undefined behavior?

Comment: @Shubham Creatin iterator which are not pointing inside the container or are one-past-the-end iteratirs is illegal for all standard iterators. At the last iteration you are decrementing iterator equal to `begin()`, which takes you outside container.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot True, but after decrementing the iterator in the last cycle, we are not using it or dereferencing it. So how does this affect the program?

Comment: @Shubham mere act of creating iterator outside of container is UB. It does not matter if you do not dereference it. For complex containers, iterator creation might access container. For arrays/vectors and segmented memory, you migh find that `--begin > begin`